# Поиск пары значений в DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
col_1|col_2|info|
-----------------
val1 | val2| 33 |
val4 | val3| 32 |
```

И есть пара значений, информацию по которым надо извлечь `(val4, val3)`.

Какой оптимальный запрос составить, чтобы получить информацию из колонки `info`?

Кроме как использовать дважды метод `query()` на ум ничего не приходит.

Comment: не совсем понятно зачем здесь использовать метод `.query()` _дважды_?

Comment: @MaxU да забыл, что в один можно запихнуть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
res = df.query("col_1 == 'val4' and col_2 == 'val3'")["info"]
```

---

пример:

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]:
  col_1 col_2  info
0  val1  val2    11
1  val4  val3    22

In [82]: res = df.query("col_1 == 'val4' and col_2 == 'val3'")["info"]

In [83]: res
Out[83]:
1    22
Name: info, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и по-другому, примерно так (пишу по памяти):

```
res = df.loc[(df["col_1"] == 'val4') & (df["col_2"] == 'val3'),["info"]]
```

Comment: выглядит правильно ;)